# Return rows with max/min values at bottom of dataframe (python/pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, max, min

I want to write a function that can look at a dataframe, find the max or min value in a specified column, then return the entire datafrane with the row(s) containing the max or min value at the bottom.

I have made it so that the rows with the max or min value alone get returned.

```
def findAggregate(df, transType, columnName=None):

    if transType == 'max1Column':
        return df[df[columnName] == df[columnName].max()]

    elif transType == 'min1Column':
        return df[df[columnName] == df[columnName].min()]
```

Given the dataframe below, I want to check col2 for the MIN value

Original Dataframe:

```
col1     col2     col3
blue     2        dog
orange   18       cat
black    6        fish
```

Expected output:

```
col1     col2     col3
blue     2        dog
orange   18       cat
black    6        fish
blue     2        dog
```

Actual output:

```
col1     col2     col3
blue     2        dog
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `idxmin` or `idxmax`:

*edited to `.loc` after AndyL's comment*

```
df.append(df.loc[df['col2'].idxmin()], ignore_index=True)

     col1  col2  col3
0    blue     2   dog
1  orange    18   cat
2   black     6  fish
3    blue     2   dog
```

Comment: `idxmax` and `idxmin` return index, not the integer index. The question doesn't specify the index. Therefore, if the index is not `rangeindex`, this will fail. I think using `loc` as in other answer is safer.

Comment: Good point, edited and noted your comment in the answer @AndyL.

Answer (score 6):

#### Focus on the index values

And use one `loc`

```
i = df.col2.idxmin()
df.loc[[*df.index] + [i]]

     col1  col2  col3
0    blue     2   dog
1  orange    18   cat
2   black     6  fish
0    blue     2   dog
```

---

Same idea but with Numpy and `iloc`

```
i = np.arange(len(df))
a = df.col2.to_numpy().argmin()
df.iloc[np.append(i, a)]

     col1  col2  col3
0    blue     2   dog
1  orange    18   cat
2   black     6  fish
0    blue     2   dog
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in oneliner:

```
df.append(df.loc[df['col2'].idxmin()])
```

Output:

```
     col1  col2  col3
0    blue     2   dog
1  orange    18   cat
2   black     6  fish
0    blue     2   dog
```

Answer (score 2):

So `sort_values`

```
df.append(df.sort_values('col2').iloc[[0]])
Out[764]: 
     col1  col2  col3
0    blue     2   dog
1  orange    18   cat
2   black     6  fish
0    blue     2   dog
```

If need `max`

```
df.append(df.sort_values('col2').iloc[[-1]])
```

adding both `min` and `max`

```
df.append(df.sort_values('col2').iloc[[0,-1]])
Out[765]: 
     col1  col2  col3
0    blue     2   dog
1  orange    18   cat
2   black     6  fish
0    blue     2   dog
1  orange    18   cat
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it various ways. Here is one:

```
def findAggregate(df, transType, columnName=None):

    if transType == 'max1Column':
        return df.append(df.loc[df['col2'].idxmax()])

    elif transType == 'min1Column':
        return df.append(df.loc[df['col2'].idxmin()])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
In [30]: df.append(df.loc[lambda x:x.col2 == x.col2.min()]).reset_index(drop=True)
Out[30]:
     col1  col2  col3
0    blue     2   dog
1  orange    18   cat
2   black     6  fish
3    blue     2   dog
```